# Sync project across multiple computers - cannot resolve symbol afterwards

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I sync my gradle projects to a usb stick and then I snyc two computers with it. Both are used by myself only, I'm just switching machines regularly (home vs work in my case).

I often get `cannot resolve symbol` (*mostly with all support v4 classes only*) exceptions from the IDE (compling works though) after this that can't be repaired anymore...

Any ideas how to solve this? And especially how to avoid this?

**What I do already**

1. I have defined a build directory outside of the projects to avoid conflicts there based on wrong intermediate files like following:

   ```
   allprojects {
       buildDir = "M:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
   }
   ```

**What I try if the problem occurs**

1. I make a `Invalidate Caches - Invalidate and Restart` in android studio => does nearly never help
2. I delete the `.idea` folder from my project => helps sometimes, is not very convenient, as I need to import the project again and set up the sdk again afterwards... and it does not always help either
3. after syncing my project I make a clean build

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most beautiful solution, but it's the best I found.

If I delete the `.idea/libraries` folder after syncing, this solves the issue.